# Is it possible to make an Html.EditorFor greyed out?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, view

I have this so far and it is readonly, but I would like it to be greyed out. I need it to be an editorFor because I am using bootstrap and it looks better than a textbox.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

Comment: _I need it to be an EditorFor_? No you dont. `TextBoxFor()` will generate the <input>. Its the html attributes (the `@class = "form-control"`) that determines what it looks like which can just as easily be added using `TextBoxFor()`

Comment: You are right, I got it using the TextBoxFor() and adding background color to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TextBoxFor, you just need to rewrite it a little bit:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

That way it adds your `form-control` class.